# Need to convert array

Tags: javascript

My input is an array in the form of:
`['[1,2,3]','[1,2,3]','[1,2,3]']`

I need to convert it to
`[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`

```js
args = '[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]'
args = args.split('[]')
args.forEach(x => args[0] = Array(x));
console.log(args)
```

Tried this but wouldn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is your input `['[1,2,3]','[1,2,3]','[1,2,3]']` or `'[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]'`?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you edited the question to make it clear whether the intended input (that is *args*) is as described in the text of your question or as shown in the code snippet. The former is an array of strings and the latter is a string.

Answer (score 2):

You could just let the JSON parser do the work.

```js
let args = '[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]';
let args_array = JSON.parse('[' + args + ']');

console.log('args', args);
console.log('args_array', args_array);
```